# How to delete trigonometric functions in a scientific calculator?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added a delete button in my scientific calculator app, when the button is clicked it will delete the input one after the other.
I use the below code to archive that.

```
if(data.equals("del")) {
    String enteredInput = input.getText().toString();
        if(enteredInput.length() > 0) {
            enteredInput = enteredInput.substring(0, enteredInput.length()-1);
            currentDisplayedInput = enteredInput;
            inputToBeParsed = enteredInput;
            input.setText(currentDisplayedInput);
        }
}
```

My problem here is that when I'm using trigonometric functions like "sin" the delete button deletes the strings one by one. I want the delete button to delete the "sin" at once.
Please how can I do that.

I have tried doing it this way:

```
 if(data.equals("del")) {
        String enteredInput = input.getText().toString();
            if (enteredInput == "sin("){
                enteredInput = enteredInput.substring(0, enteredInput.length()-4);
                currentDisplayedInput = enteredInput;
                inputToBeParsed = enteredInput;
                input.setText(currentDisplayedInput);
            }

            else if(enteredInput.length() > 0) {
                enteredInput = enteredInput.substring(0, enteredInput.length()-1);
                currentDisplayedInput = enteredInput;
                inputToBeParsed = enteredInput;
                input.setText(currentDisplayedInput);
            }

    }
```

But still the problem is not solved.

Comment: You could perform a string match that says if you're about to delete, `sin` or other functions rather than blindly do one character at a time. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: You can use regexes to replace those words with an empty string.

Comment: I have edited the question, you can see what I have tried @  cricket_007

Comment: Please can you explain more @ Kling Klang as I don't even know what is regexes, I am new to android studio.

Comment: You just want to delete all the input in the EditText ? @AliyuMarke

Comment: No is just the trigonometric function, for example the user entered 1+2+3+sin(90) and he wants to delete the sin(90) only by clicking the delete button @ dglozano